how to add label in facedgrid ggplot2

i have this image and i want to add letters in each square, like this:

but i want to maintain the labels "50" "75" and the minutes, is this possible? here's my code:
Buoy <-
joined_lists %>%
  filter(!is.na(buoyancy),
         !is.na(period),
         !is.na(air_force)) %>% 
  mutate(hora = hour(date_time),
         average = factor(average, 
                          levels = c("30min", "5min", "1min"))) %>% 
group_by(hora, average, level, air_force) %>% 
  summarise(buoyancy = mean(buoyancy, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = hora, y = buoyancy, color = factor(air_force))) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  facet_grid(average ~ level, scales = "fixed", shrink = TRUE)+
  labs(y = expression(B(m^2/s^3)),
       x = "Time(h)",
       color = "Regime\
do vento", )+
  theme_bw(base_size = 16,
           base_family = "Helvetica")+
  theme(strip.text = element_text(face = "bold", size = 16),
        legend.key = element_rect(color = "white"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5))

tag_facet(p = Buoy, x = -Inf, y = Inf, open = "", close = ")" , tag_pool = letters)


The tag_facet source code seems to explicitly remove facet strips with + theme(strip.text = element_blank(),strip.background = element_blank()). To avoid this, you can write your customized tag_facet without that code snippet
Buoy <-
joined_lists %>%
  filter(!is.na(buoyancy),
         !is.na(period),
         !is.na(air_force)) %>% 
  mutate(hora = hour(date_time),
         average = factor(average, 
                          levels = c("30min", "5min", "1min"))) %>% 
group_by(hora, average, level, air_force) %>% 
  summarise(buoyancy = mean(buoyancy, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = hora, y = buoyancy, color = factor(air_force))) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  facet_grid(average ~ level, scales = "fixed", shrink = TRUE)+
  labs(y = expression(B(m^2/s^3)),
       x = "Time(h)",
       color = "Regime\
do vento", )+
  theme_bw(base_size = 16,
           base_family = "Helvetica")+
  theme(strip.text = element_text(face = "bold", size = 16),
        legend.key = element_rect(color = "white"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5))

tag_facet_custom <- function(p, open = "(", close = ")", tag_pool = letters, x = -Inf, y = Inf, 
                      hjust = -0.5, vjust = 1.5, fontface = 2, family = "", ...) {
  
  gb <- ggplot_build(p)
  lay <- gb$layout$layout
  tags <- cbind(lay, label = paste0(open, tag_pool[lay$PANEL], close), x = x, y = y)
  p + geom_text(data = tags, aes_string(x = "x", y = "y", label = "label"), ..., hjust = hjust, 
                vjust = vjust, fontface = fontface, family = family, inherit.aes = FALSE)
}

tag_facet_custom(p = Buoy, x = -Inf, y = Inf, open = "", close = ")" , tag_pool = letters)

